# Fermat's Last Theorem for n=3 : altered proof

Tags: number-theory

A standard proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, for $n=3$ goes like this:
http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-proof-for-n3.html

For my own understanding, I wrote an altered proof for this part:
**$2p(p^2+3q^2)$ can never be a cube of a positive integer (where p,q are co-primes)**.

I am trying to figure out where I failed. I will be happy to re-edit if the question doesn't make sense.

---

Assume $2p(p^2+3q^2) = z^3$.

**Case-1) Let's say $p$ has a prime factor $d$ ($d$ is neither 2 nor 3).**

Assume $p=dp_1$.
This makes: $2d^3p_1^3+6dp_1q^2=z^3$.
Since first and second terms have $d$ as common factor, it forces third term (and thus $z$) to have $d$ as a factor.

Assume $z=dz_1$
This makes: $2d^3p_1^3+6dp_1q^2=d^3z_1^3$
Cancelling $d$ we get: $2d^2p_1^3+6p_1q^2=d^2z_1^3$

Since first and third terms have $d$ as common factor it forces second term (and thus $q$) to have $d$ as a factor, which is a contradiction (since p,q are co-primes)

Instead, if $p$ had another $d$ as factor, the above procedure can be continued till the second term exhausts all factors of $d$ and still leave first and second terms with extra factors of $d$. That eventually forces $q$ to have $d$ as a factor, which is a contradiction.

This procedure can be done for all prime factors of p.

**Case-2) If $p$ has a prime factor as $2$**
This can be worked out same as Case-1.

**Case-3) If $p$ has a prime factor as $3$**
This can be worked out same as Case-1.

---

That leaves us with $p=1$.
$2p(p^2+3q^2)= z^3$.
It can be ruled out since $(p^2+3q^2)$ is an odd number (since p,q have opposite parity). The expression lacks $2^2$ in order to form a cube.

---

Comment: All your argument shows is that $p=4m^3$ for some integer $m$.

Comment: @MikeBennett, Could you elaborate? I tried to show that if posted equation were to be true, then p has to be 1. That is a contradiction since it reduces to $2*OddNumber$ (which can never be a cube of an integer). I am sure I missed something here (both in my proof and in your comment). Thank you.

Comment: If $ 2p \not\mid 3 $ then $2p$ is a cube implies $2p = 8m^3$, if $ 2p \mid 3 $ then $\begin{aligned} & 2p = 9k^3 = 72m^3, \ p = 36m^3  ~\\ & p^2+3q^2=3n^3 = ((36m^3)^2 + 3q^2) = 3(432m^6 + q^2)=3(q^2 + 3(12m^3)^2) ~\\ & n^3 = q^2 + 3(12m^3)^2 \\ & 12m^3 = 3b(a-b)(a+b) \\ & 2p = 72m^3 = 6 \times 3b(a-b)(a+b) = 9(2b(a-b)(a+b)) = 9k^3\\ & 2b(a-b)(a+b) = k^3\\ & 2b = u^3, \ a-b = v^3,\ a+b = w^3, \  u^3 + v^3 = w^3  \\ \end{aligned}$

Comment: I realized my mistake. If $p=d^3$ as factors, first term will have $d^9$, second term will have $d^3$ and third gets forced to have $d^3$. Thus the cancellations stop. The procedure halts before $p$ could become 1 (one).

Comment: @miket, I will go over your comment slowly. Thanks for feedback.